# unable to set property on object using value with acceptable conversion type

Tags: log4net, log4net-appender

I am using async forwarding appender.

https://github.com/cjbhaines/Log4Net.Async

Below is my Configuration

```
<appender name="asyncForwarder" type="Log4Net.Async.AsyncForwardingAppender,Log4Net.Async">
  <bufferSize value="2000"/>
<appender-ref ref="AMQAppender" />
<appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
```

Buffer size value 2000 is not getting set and get this below warning.

```
Unable to set property [bufferSize] on object using value [2000] (with accepatble convresion types)
```

What am I doing wrong with configuration, please advise.

Comment: Do you get the same error using a lower value?

Comment: yes, the datatype of buffersize is int? I am not sure if "?" (nullable) type is a problem here.

Comment: Yes, that's it, changing BufferSize to be a normal int instead of a nullable one fixes the problem: log4net's xml config type converter code cannot cope with nullables - as a workaround, you could set the buffer value in code.

Comment: Raised https://github.com/cjbhaines/Log4Net.Async/issues/13

Comment: Thank you @stuartd add this as answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @stuartd didn't post his answer in answer section instead of comment and me being a person like closure. Here is the answer from stuartd:

Change buffersize to be a int instead of int?